# decimal in c# misunderstanding?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, decimal

*(while trying to analyze how `decimal` works ) && after reading [@jonskeet article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx)  and seeing [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) , and thinking for the last 4 hours ,* 
I have some questions :

in [this link](http://mathsfirst.massey.ac.nz/Algebra/Decimals/SigFig.htm) they say something very simple :

`1.5 x 10^2` has `2` significant figures

`1.50 x 10^2` has `3` significant figures.

`1.500 x 10^2` has `4` significant figures etc...

ok...we get the idea.

*from jon's article  :*

```
 sign * mantissa / 10^exponent
```

> As usual, the sign is just a single bit, but there are 96 bits of
>   mantissa and 5 bits of exponent

```
 ^ _ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^___ ^^^^^

 1 _                     96                         5
```

ok

so max **mantiss** val = `2^96-1 = 79228162514264337593543950335` which is : `7.9228162514264*10^28` *(according to my iphone... could'nt see exponent representation in windows calc.)*

notice :

`7.9228162514264*10^28` has **14** significant figures (according to examples above)

now the part with the 5 bit in exponent is irrelevant because its in the *denominator* - so i need the min val which is 2^0

**question #1 :**

msdn say : [image] `28-29 significant digits`

but according to my sample (*`1.500 x 10^2` has `4` significant figures*) they have **2**   significant figures which is `7.9` ( 7 and 9).

if msdn would have written :

```
±79228162514264337593543950335 × 10^0
```

i would understand this ,  since all significant digits are **in the expression**.

*why do they write 28-29 but display 2 ?*

**question #2 :**

how will decimal representation ( mantiss && exponent) will be displayed for the value 0.5 ?

*the max denominator can be `2^32-1 --> 31`*

thanks guys.

**question #3 :**

1+96+5 = 102 bits.

msdn says :

> The decimal keyword denotes a 128-bit data type.

```
128-102 = 26
```

could understnad from article why there isnt a usage to those 26 bits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They've given the *range* to just two significant digits, but specified the *precision* separately. That's why the range is listed as "approximate range".

The `decimal` representation of 0.5 would be a mantissa of 5 and an exponent of 1 (which is treated in the inverse sense to normal, i.e. it's *effectively* -1).

Comment: @RoyiNamir: No, the mantissa is 5. What made you think it's got anything to do with 2^5? I suspect you've misunderstood what a mantissa is.

Comment: oh sorry...:) after 4 hours of searching im thinking in base 2 :)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: The base is irrelevant though - you never raise a base to the power of a mantissa; that's what an *exponent* is for.

Comment: can i say that the precision ( decimal digits at the right to the point) is accurate within 28 digits ? so if i have 2 fractions of 28 decimals being added - the result will be accurate ? is it true to say ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir The decimal fraction's precision is accurate within a range of 2^96/10 providing the number is between 0 and 1.

Comment: @DannyVarod sorry i dont understand this. my question is simple. `i can work safely accurate with X digits to the right of the decimal point`. what is X ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir You can work safely with a total of N digits including those to the left of the decimal point. In other words, depends on the rest of the number.

Answer (score 3):

> why do they write 28-29 but display 2?

For readability. It says "Approximate range" and 7.9E28 is more readable than 79228162514264337593543950335 (E0 here, not E1).

> how will decimal representation ( mantiss && exponent) will be displayed for the value 0.5 ?

The exponent's range is -28...0, however, it is stored (and received via constructor parameters) as an absolute value of 0...28.

So 0.5 Would have the same mantissa representation as 5 with an exponent of -1 (stored as 1).

Comment: You're getting confused between exponent and mantissa in the "if the exponent is 5 bits" part. Which exact bit of MSDN do you believe to be inaccurate?

Comment: a. The mantissa is 96bits, the exponent is 5 - where exactly did I confuse the two. b. "The scaling factor is implicitly the number 10, raised to an exponent ranging from 0 to 28." - There is no mention of negative exponents.

Comment: So the exponent doesn't have its own sign? - How do you know if you have to use E+n or E-n then?

Comment: (I was just in the middle of adding another comment, btw.) The exponent for decimal is always in the range 0-28, as specified in the documentation. It's then *used* in the inverse sense of a tradtional exponent, as documented (value = sign * mantissa / 10^exponent)

Comment: I still think your statement of "If the exponent is 5bits and is signed, then the full range is -2^31 .. 2^31 - 1" is extremely confused and/or confusing. I certainly don't know what you mean by it, despite having a pretty good understanding of `decimal`. Note that the range depends on the size of the mantissa as well as the exponent.

Comment: Ahh so it is actually -28 to 0.

Comment: It depends on how you want to view it. It's *stored* as if it were an unsigned integer in the range 0-28, and that non-negative value is used in a sort of "inverse" way, or as the normal exponent of a divisor instead of a multiplier. I think that's the clearest way of looking at it, personally, but YMMV. I think it's confusing to claim in this answer that the range is -28 to 0 (with no usage or storage explanation) when the *documented* range is 0-28 with a complete explanation of how it's stored and used.