# C# Decimal.Epsilon

Tags: c#, .net, decimal, epsilon

Why doesn't `Decimal` data type have `Epsilon` field?

[From the manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx), the range of `decimal` values is ±1.0 × 10e−28 to ±7.9 × 10e28.

[The description of `Double.Epsilon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.epsilon.aspx):

> Represents the smallest positive `Double` value greater than zero

So it seems, `Decimal` has such a (non-trivial) value too. But why isn't it easily accessible?

I do understand that +1.0 × 10e−28 is exactly the smallest positive Decimal value greater than zero:

```
decimal Decimal_Epsilon = new decimal(1, 0, 0, false, 28); //1e-28m;
```

By the way, there are a couple of questions that give information about Decimal data type's internal representation:

- [decimal in c# misunderstanding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614592/decimal-in-c-sharp-misunderstanding)
- [What's the second minimum value that a decimal can represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241842/whats-the-second-minimum-value-that-a-decimal-can-represent)

Here's an example where `Epsilon` would be useful.

Lets say I have a weighted sum of values from some sampling set and sum of weights (or count) of samples taken. Now I want to compute the weighted mean value. But I know that the sum of weights (or count) may be still zero. To prevent division by zero I could do `if... else...` and check for the zero. Or I could write like this:

```
T weighted_mean = weighted_sum / (weighted_count + T.Epsilon)
```

This code is shorter in my eye. Or, alternatively I can skip the `+ T.Epsilon` and instead initialize with:

```
T weighted_count = T.Epsilon;
```

I can do this when I know that the values of real weights are never close to `Epsilon`.

And for some data types and use cases this is maybe even faster since it does not involve branches. As I understand, the processors are not able to take both branches for computation, even when the branches are short. And I may know that the zeros occur randomly at 50% rate :=) For `Decima`l, the speed aspect is likely not important or even positively useful in the first case though.

My code may be generic (for example, generated) and I do not want to write separate code for decimals. Therefore one would like to see that `Decimal` have similar interface as other real-valued types.

Comment: Not sure why so many downvotes; this seems like a valid question.  Downvoters care to comment?

Comment: @Tanzelax Some people are trigger happy and prefer to assume that the question is a homework, plain stupid, not researched enough etc. I myself think it's a splendid question and I'd give it +1 but my votes for today are out. If I remember tomorrow I'll upgrade it. Very good questions indeed. (Also, downgrading without commenting is a very bad habit, borderline to bullying - as well as not re-grading once the misunderstanding has been resolved.)

Comment: Covered here for double.Epsilon, same idea: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2411661/17034

Comment: It's a bummer there isn't one.  I really would like to have this as I have a SpinEdit, whose value is of decimal type, and it controls the aspect ratio of our view.  If I don't want users to be able to type in 0, I don't know what to set the SpinEdit's MinValue to if I don't want to allow 0, but I do want smaller numbers (0.1, 0.01, 0.001, etc.)

Answer (score 14):

Contrary to that definition, epsilon is actually a concept used to eliminate the ambiguity of conversion between binary and decimal representations of values.  For example, 0.1 in decimal doesn't have a simple binary representation, so when you declare a double as 0.1, it is actually setting that value to an approximate representation in binary.  If you add that binary representation number to itself 10 times (mathematically), you get a number that is approximately 1.0, but not exactly.  An epsilon will let you fudge the math, and say that the approximate representation of 0.1 added to itself can be considered equivalent to the approximate representation of 0.2.

This approximation that is caused by the nature of the representations is not needed for the decimal value type, which is already a decimal representation.  This is why any time you need to deal with actual numbers and numbers which are themselves not approximations (i.e. money as opposed to mass), the correct floating point type to use is decimal and not double.

Comment: Yes, but is this then The Only use of decimal? What about its greater precision (though the range is less)?
Also, I may want to know the minimum positive value of decimal for some purposes, just like for other real numeric types, I do not think the decimal is less worthy member in general calculation. It has its advantages.

Comment: The question was regarding an epsilon and why decimal was lacking one, so that's what I answered.  At its core, the decimal value type is simply a particular base 10 floating point type.  There could be any number of reasons to use it instead of double, including the large amount of bits devoted to its mantissa.

Comment: So the type's Epsilon field gives information about the precision of conversion between decimal base and the given type, and no other useful information about the type?

Comment: That is basically how an epsilon is intended to be used, yes. In actuality, it should also be defined based on the expected precision of the representation, and is relevant primarily to comparisons between two numbers (at what precision can you consider two numbers equivalent); when you start multiplying together doubles, or adding number with different exponent values together, the epsilon should almost never equal the "smallest nonzero positive number with a representation".

Comment: "For example, 0.1 in decimal doesn't have a simple binary representation" - I think you mean "in double"?

Comment: @kristianp 0.1 in decimal doesn't have a simple double representation.

Comment: @AaronFranke ok, so they mean in decimal numbers, not the .net Decimal type.  My mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Smallest number I can calculate for decimal is:

```
public static decimal DecimalEpsilon = (decimal) (1 / Math.Pow(10, 28));
```

This is from running the following in a C# Interactive Window:

```
for (int power = 0; power <= 50; power++) { Console.WriteLine($"1 / 10^{power} = {((decimal)(1 / (Math.Pow(10, power))))}"); }
```

Which has the following output:

```
1 / 10^27 = 0.000000000000000000000000001
1 / 10^28 = 0.0000000000000000000000000001
1 / 10^29 = 0
1 / 10^30 = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

If we just think about the 96 bit mantissa, the Decimal type can be thought of as having an epsilon equal to the reciprocal of a BigInteger constructed with 96 set bits. That is obviously too small a number to represent with current intrinsic value types.

In other words, we would need a "BigReal" value to represent such a small fraction.

And frankly, that is just the "granularity" of the epsilon. We would then need to know the exponent (bits 16-23 of the highest Int32 from GetBits()) to arrive at the "real" epsilon for a GIVEN decimal value.

Obviously, the meaning of "epsilon" for Decimal is variable. You can use the granularity epsilon with the exponent and come up with a specific epsilon for a GIVEN decimal.

But consider the following rather problematic situation:

```
[TestMethod]
public void RealEpsilonTest()
{
    var dec1 = Decimal.Parse("1.0");
    var dec2 = Decimal.Parse("1.00");
    Console.WriteLine(BitPrinter.Print(dec1, " "));
    Console.WriteLine(BitPrinter.Print(dec2, " "));
}
```

> DEC1: 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   00000000 00001010
>
> DEC2; 00000000 00000010 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   00000000 01100100

Despite the two parsed values seemingly being equal, their representation is not the same!

The moral of the story is... be very careful that you thoroughly understand Decimal before THINKING that you understand it !!!

HINT:

If you want the epsilon for Decimal (theoretically), create a UNION `([StructLayout[LayoutKind.Explicit])` combining Decimal(128 bits) and BigInteger(96 bits) and Exponent(8 bits). The getter for Epsilon would return the correct BigReal value based on granularity epsilon and exponent; assuming, of course, the existence of a `BigReal` definition (which I've been hearing for quite some time, will be coming).

The granularity epsilon, by the way, would be a constant or a static field...

```
static grain = new BigReal(1 / new BitInteger(new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF });
```

HOMEWORK: Should the last byte to BigInteger be `0xFF` or `0x7F` (or something else altogether)?

PS: If all of that sounds rather more complicated than you were hoping, ... consider that comp science pays reasonably well. /-)

Comment: Can You please summarise Your idea in a shorter form? I have trouble following it at the moment. As I understand, +1.0 × 10e−28 can be represented as Decimal. I update my question accordingly to give the expression.